# Is ( ... ) a subshell in this code or something else?

Tags: sh, posix, subshell

In this POSIX shell function of mine:

```
disable_mouse_for_a_second()
{
    if xinput --disable "$1" 2> /dev/null
    then
        (
            sleep 1s
            xinput --enable "$1"
        ) &
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
```

---

Is `(` ... `)` a subshell in this code or something else?

Comment: Answer -- yes, it's a subshell that backgrounds `sleep` and `xinput`. It's just `( sleep 1s; xinput --enable "$1"; ) &` spread over multiple lines (which is 100% OK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is **Yes**. The reason why is the block in question is nothing more than the single line:

```
( sleep 1s; xinput --enable "$1"; ) &
```

spread over multiple lines. It simply executes (and backgrounds) the `sleep` and `xinput` commands.

The two primary *compound commands* written over multiple lines you will see are:

```
(list)        ## and 
{ list; }
```

The distinction between the two is `(list)` is executed in a *subshell* environment and variable assignments and builtin commands that affect the shell's environment do not remain in effect after the command completes.

`{ list; }` list is simply executed in the *current shell environment*.